# Java stream - take inner element after GroupBy

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I group by cars list to the ones that have name and one that do not.

```
cars.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(car -> IdUtil.isEmpty(car.getName().equals(""))));
```

In this example I will get `Map<Boolean, List<Cars>>`

Questions:

1. I want to get a different inner member from each group so that I will get 
   `Map<Boolean, List<wheels>>` using a condition

> return ((car.getName().equals(""))? FrontWheel ? rearWheels;

2. Can I controll the key value?
   for this example using a string that says
   "Rear"-> Cars List
   "Front"-> Cars List

Thanks.

Comment: Consider using `Collectors.partitioningBy` instead of `groupingBy` with a `boolean` key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For #1, you can use can chain a `mapping` `Collector` to map the `List<Cars>` to something else :

```
Map<Boolean,List<wheels>> map1 =
cars.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(car -> IdUtil.isEmpty(car.getName().equals("")),
                                   Collectors.mapping(car -> ((car.getName().equals(""))? car.getFrontWheel() : car.getRearWheels(),Collectors.toList()));
```

For #2, there should be no problem to change the key to what you want :

```
Map<String,List<Cars>> map2 =
cars.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(car -> IdUtil.isEmpty(car.getName().equals(""))?"Front":"Rear"));
```

Of course you can combine the two and get a `Map<String,List<wheels>>`.

Note : this code is not tested, so I may have some typos.